# How to have a customized user profile for certain users?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

We need a customized user profile page for users that signed up this month (some marketing promo).

What would be the simplest way of doing this? Again its only for users that signed up this month. Please provide detailed instructions if possible.

Thank you

Comment: You should start accepting more answers to the questions you asked. What did you try, so far, to get a custom user profile page?

Comment: This depends on what approach you use for your user profiles so far, and on the kind of customization you want to do (just different markup/output or whole new fields), so you need to elaborate a bit.

Comment: And BTW, _explicitly_ asking for detailed instructions is usually not helpful for getting them - it just sounds more like if you want others to do your work for you, and less like asking for help.

Comment: Still a +1, as the problem/feature is an interesting one ;)

Comment: Are you willing to develop a module for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In page.tpl.php

```
body class="<?php if(arg(1) == 'user') echo date('m-Y'); ?>"
```

Style with css.  You could get a little more explicit with that if so only certain profiles get a class.

Instead of just `echo date('m-Y');`, query the database to get the created value and strtotime.